# VSCode debug mode returns empty for a variable, but I can print the variable when not in debug

Tags: python-3.x, vscode-debugger

The following line of code when runs normally outside debug mode, prints out the variables for ModelInfo and final_result.

`ModelInfo, final_result = status_for_all_models('id')`

However, when I run the code in debug mode in VSCode, I get an object with empty attribute(._registery) for ModelInfo and an empty [] for final_result.
I am using python for programming and I have the following in launch.json file as configuration for my debugger.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Any ideas for how I can make it work in debug mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved after I added below lines to the configuration for debugger at launch.json

```
"justMyCode": false
"cwd": "path/to/your/project"
```

as some code was run on third party library, and the working directory for retrieving some files needed to be defined precisely.